# Ng-Class to compare range of number

Tags: angular

I need to change my color when the number is outside the range .3 and .5. This is how i do it.

```
<th 
  scope="col" 
  [ngClass]="{'changeColor' : item.number<= 26.5 && item.number>= 26.5}"
>
  {{item.number}}
</th>
```

But it does not work. What is needed to be changed? thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The condition is wrong here a number can't be <= and >= at same time, the operator should be OR here :-

```
<th scope="col"  [ngClass]="{'changeColor' : item.number<= 26.5 || item.number>= 26.5}">{{item.number}}</th>
```

Comment: This is resolved. Thanks!